# ruby 1.92 bad interpreter: permission denied

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cygwin

New to Ruby and using RailsTutorial book to learn. I'm on Windows 7 machine using cygwin.

Anyway, I started using Ruby 1.8.7 (default on cygwin) and installed the gems, rails, git, etc. All working fine, but got to step to deploy app with Heroku and it required Ruby 1.9.2.

After research, I decided to uninstall Ruby 1.8.7 (through cygwin uninstall) and then compiled from source Ruby 1.9.2. I reran gems and installed rails again.

When I run `rails -v` though, I get `-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: Permission denied`.

Any ideas on how to get rails working again?

Thanks!

Here's output of gem env:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.12
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i386-cygwin]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-cygwin
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/Philip/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Umm ... fix the permissions of `/usr/bin/ruby.exe` ?

Comment: Can you post the output of this command: `gem env`?

Comment: updated my question with the gem env output

Answer (score 0):

Fix the permissions of `/usr/bin/ruby.exe` as said in the comment.

And if that doesn't help,
I'd say you re-install everything again but this time with `Administrative privileges`.
Open up a terminal with Administrative privileges and repeat the whole process.

BTW, How are you installing Rails on Windows?
Are you using [Rails Installer for Windows by EngineYard](http://www.railsinstaller.org/)??
If not, go take a look at the link above and [railsinstaller-for-windows-EY-blog](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/railsinstaller-for-windows-2-0-0-preview-release/)

Comment: OP said he is using cygwin, Windows admin privileges do not apply then.

Comment: Somehow, after I closed cygwin and started up again the rails -v command worked and looks like i'm back on track. Though I still have some worries about old version 1.87 being around even though i had uninstalled it through cygwin prior to installing 1.92..so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `atlassian-stash` gem under `cygwin 2.3.1 x86_64` and `ruby 2.2.3p173`. I tried to fix the permissions for `ruby.exe` and all the script files, but even `rwxrwxrwx` permission didn't help.

The stange thing was that the scipt was running smoothly when called directly, but if it was a part of the `git alias`, it was getting me `/usr/bin/ruby.exe: Bad interpreter: permission deined` error.

I found that `gem` engine created some auxiliary files inside `~/bin` folder. Removing those files helped.